# how to make python to find my .egg(s)

Tags: python, python-2.7, egg

I installed several packages as .egg in directoryA. How to make python to find them? I put the following line to .bashrc, but not work.

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:directoryA"
```

Anything missing? What solution is a good practice to add the path of eggs to python?

I used site to add this path to my django project in wsgi file. It works. But when I run python manage.py xxx, it cannot find the installed egg packages.